# Create back,up of a SQL Server database and store it on remote machine

Tags: sql-server, powershell, vpn, database-backups

I have a SQL Server named `TheOtherSide`. It is in a different domain (`OtherDomain`).

I have another SQL Server named `MySide` in my own domain (`MyDomain`).

There is a VPN connection between the two servers that allows only TCP over port 1433.

I want to take a backup of the database `CoolDatabase` that exists on `TheOtherSide` and restore that backup on server `MySide`.

That process needs to be automated.

Any backup script I see stores the backup in `OtherDomain` where I cannot retrieve it.

Can I run a PowerShell script to create the backup that will store the backup in `MyDomain`?

Comment: A _classic_ backup (.bak) cannot _be streamed_ out of the SQL Server machine installation, you can save the backup on a shared disk or another folder and get it with  FTP or something like that. If your objective is only to backup/restore (and NOT a backup plan, like full backup, incremental backup, and log backup) you can backup/restore the database has _.bacpac_, in this case see the [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/)

Comment: This should be an answer. I also found SQLBackupAndFTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic backup (.bak) cannot be streamed out of the SQL Server machine installation.

You can save the backup on a shared disk or another folder and get it with FTP or something like that.

If your objective is only to backup/restore (and NOT a backup plan, like full backup, incremental backup, and log backup) you can backup/restore the database has *.bacpac*, in this case, you can use scripts like [dbatools PowerShell Module](https://dbatools.io/)